# Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @SystemProperty

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to read `System Property` by injecting the value.

I am trying to use http://juraj.blahunka.eu/2014/05/17/inject-jboss-system-properties/ for reference.

My code looks like

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SystemProperty {
    /*
    Full name of System Property
     */
    @Nonbinding
    String value();
}
```

and

```
public class SystemPropertyProvider {

    @Produces
    @SystemProperty("")
    String getSystemProperty(final InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        final SystemProperty annotation = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(SystemProperty.class);
        final String name = annotation.value();
        final String found = System.getProperty(name);
        if (null == found) {
            throw new RuntimeException("System property " + name + "not found");
        }
        System.out.println("serverPrivateKeyValue:" + found);

        return found;
    }
}
```

and the way I inject is

```
@Stateless
public class UniqueIdGenerator {
    private static final String COLON = ":";

    private String serverPrivateKey;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public UniqueIdGenerator() {
    }

    @Inject
    public UniqueIdGenerator(@SystemProperty("com.kb.serverPrivateKey") @Nonnull final String serverPrivateKey) {
        this.serverPrivateKey = serverPrivateKey;
    }
    ....
}
```

I deploy my `war` using `maven cargo` and set the property as

```
                 <container>
                    <containerId>wildfly8x</containerId>
                    <dependencies combine.children="append">
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <com.kb.serverPrivateKey>test</com.kb.serverPrivateKey>
                    </systemProperties>
                </container>
```

and when I deploy the app I see error as

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:57:49,676 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @SystemProperty
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @SystemProperty private com.karmabeta.services.filter.AuthTokenValidatorFilter.serverPrivateKey
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.karmabeta.services.filter.AuthTokenValidatorFilter.serverPrivateKey(AuthTokenValidatorFilter.java:0)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   - Producer Method [String] with qualifiers [@BatchProperty @Any] declared as [[UnbackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @BatchProperty public org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getString(InjectionPoint)]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:368)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:289)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:166)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:514)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 3 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:57:49,686 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "application.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @SystemProperty
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @SystemProperty private com.karmabeta.services.filter.AuthTokenValidatorFilter.serverPrivateKey
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.karmabeta.services.filter.AuthTokenValidatorFilter.serverPrivateKey(AuthTokenValidatorFilter.java:0)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   - Producer Method [String] with qualifiers [@BatchProperty @Any] declared as [[UnbackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @BatchProperty public org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getString(InjectionPoint)]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] "}}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:57:49,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name : "cargocpc.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are those classes in separate jars? have you a beans.xml in both of them?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with WildFly 8.x/CDI 1.1, it seems that your `SystemPropertyProvider` is ignored, since it is missing a bean defining annotation. Or did you put it into an explicit bean archive with a suitable `beans.xml` descriptor?

By the way, for injecting system and other environment properties, I'd recommend to have a look at Apache DeltaSpike [`@ConfigProperty`](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

By the following message in the log:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:57:49,676 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
```

The error doesn't occur in the EJB class, this message is generated by deploy of `application.war` module by class `com.karmabeta.services.filter.AuthTokenValidatorFilter`.

According to the documentacion message:

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @SystemProperty
```

> **To fix an unsatisfied dependency, either:**
>
> - create a bean which implements the bean type and has all the qualifier types of the injection point,
> - make sure that the bean you already have is in the classpath of the module with the injection point, or
> - explicitly enable an `@Alternative` bean that implements the bean type and has the appropriate qualifier types, using beans.xml.
> - enable an `@Alternative` bean that implements the bean type and has the    appropriate qualifier types, using `@Priority` annotation.

I think the second item is part of the solution, you probably have the producer in the ejb module, this makes it not visible from the war module.

Note that the `@Producer` will always only be picked up from a top-level deployment unit (e.g. a war or ear/lib), not from subdeployments.

If this is the case, you can put your producers and other components CDI in a jar file in ear/lib or directly war/classes.

I hope this help.